# Rest @PathParam doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, cxf

I'm working on a REST web service using CXF. I have published my web service and it's working fine except for the following method, which requires a parameter:

```
@GET
@Path("/capteur/{id}")  
public Capteur selectCapteurByID(@PathParam(value = "id")String id) {
System.out.println(id);
return capteurDao.getCapteur(id);
}
```

When I try to access my service using the URL: `localhost:8080/FireApp/rest/myService/myservice/capteur/11554`

I get no response and the following log message:

```
DEBUG o.a.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils - WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to annotate the endpoint as @Path instead of @WebService for it to work for REST endpoints.

Comment: @Admin, why does that not provide answers? You keep deleting the post.

Answer (score 0):

WS-Addressing is rather specific to JAX-WS/SOAP stuff and not the RESTful JAX-RS.

Are you sure your not mixing JAX-WS (@WebService) with JAX-RS in your class ?

Comment: Yes of course the annotation (@WebService is not missing) while chechking the debuging messages I also found this message : 22:18:17.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG o.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No Content-Type specified for HTTP GET